# Convert array of object to array of values of specific key

Tags: typescript

My object look something like this.

```
var fruits = [
    {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'golden'
    },
    {
        name: 'pear',
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        color: 'yellow'
    }
]
```

Now what i want is an array of the names of the fruit from the `fruit object`

```
console.log(getFruitNames(fruits)) //['apple','pear','mango']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? The problem you describe is trivial and I'd expect you to be able to find at least a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a `map` to return each name.

```js
var fruits = [
    {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'golden'
    },
    {
        name: 'pear',
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        color: 'yellow'
    }
]

console.log(getFruitNames(fruits))

function getFruitNames(fruits){
  return fruits.map(m => m.name)
}
```

Also a [TS playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDEoFdhgN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIDKYUoA5gDREkID2ANp1DfUYgmBAL4EAbnCjIY2XAGdkAXmQBtdsUIkdpCtWQByOAAcT3CIba6OPPjUNMeAEwghDm5KOsltNvZQOJhDSVp46XLz8RkxQEG4eOt6efjZkgUbkcMKcYf7IkfZGAJ4Q3LwA7okk4gC6BARcIAo8EAB0vEwAFEwQYJg4YABy+gpdcoMKAJRTDTBYIAhgwJwgyL398sOj41sKVBhbarVTfnFgWFBrE4ptWSZd5CoAfMjkbekQs6JAA)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map()` is what you need.

It will create a new array populated with the results of calling the provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var fruits = [
    {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'golden'
    },
    {
        name: 'pear',
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        color: 'yellow'
    }
];


console.log(fruits.map(x => x.name))
```

more about `map` can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map